# ¿Como obtener el ultimo objeto de una relación con queryset Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo un modelo llamado `Pedido` y otro llamado `LineasEstadoPedido` que guarda los estados por los que va pasando el pedido.

Necesito obtener el ultimo estado de cada pedido con una consulta para después utilizar los pedidos que estén en una estado concreto.

Los estados los estoy almacenando con un choice:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    f_ped = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    p_prod = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=2) #precio producto
    p_envio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    cp_nom_producto = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    cp_talla = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    cp_marca = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    cp_nombre_completo = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None) #nombre del comprador
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, related_name='perfil_comprador') 
    vendedor = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, related_name='perfil_vendedor', blank=True, null=True)
    cp_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)


class LineasEstadoPedido(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES_ESTADO_PEDIDO)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Choice:

```
CHOICES_ESTADO_PEDIDO = (
    (1,'Pendiente de pago'),
    (2,'Pagado'),
    (3,'Error de Pago'),
    (4,'Pendiente recogida'),
    (5,'Enviado'),
    (6,'Entregado'),
    (7,'No recogido'), 
    (8,'Error envio'), 
    (9,'Incidencia'), # Estado marcado por comprador para solicitar devolución de pago
    (10,'Completado'),
)
```

Ahora mismo estoy intentando algo como esto:

```
for p in Pedido.objects.all():
    if p.lineasestadopedido.all().last() == 9:
        return p
```

Estoy usando *Python 3.5* y *Django 1.11*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya casi lo tenías

```
pedidos_estado9 = []
for p in Pedido.objects.all():
    if p.lineasestadopedido.all().last().estado == 9:
        pedidos_estado9.appens(p)

return pedidos_estado9
```

Esto es retorna todos los pedidos que tengan en estado 9

Para sumar un atributo de una lista en una sola linea lo puedes hacer así:

```
total_pedidos = sum(p.p_prop for p in pedidos_estado9)
```

Comment: ¿No hay una forma de generar eso mismo en un queryset para que no tenga que extraerlo en una función? Es por simplificar un poco más.

Comment: es que después no puedo utilizar la funcion Sum para sumar el campo p_prod de todos los pedidos

Comment: si el ultimo estado siembre va a ser 9 si se puede hacer una consulta, pero si luego del nueve puede ser 10 , o 1 o 2, etc no se puede hacer una consulta , puedes usar la funcción sum de python te lo añado a mi respuesta

Comment: Es caso es que esa funcionalidad la necesito en varios sitios y en algunos casos necesito hacer un distinct de usuarios, en otros necesito hacer una media o una suma, entonces era por sabes si puedo obtener un queryset. Si no es posible no pasa nada, me sirve esa solución